# Having trouble installing "car" package in RStudio to run LeveneTest()

Tags: r, installation, package

```
#part b
#based on some online sources, it'll be easier to add BP to the original data.frame then trim it down a bit
install.packages("car",dependencies=TRUE)
#we also need this package
hyper$BP <- (hyper$systolic + hyper$diastolic)/2
leveneTest(hyper$BP,hyper$diet)
```

It seems I am able to install the "car" package, but when I try to call the library(car) afterwards, I get this error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘car’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]): there is no package called ‘zip’
```

Then it continues to say

```
Error in leveneTest(hyper$BP, hyper$diet) : 
  could not find function "leveneTest"
```

I am trying to run the Levene's Test but I can't seem to find the right dependencies

Comment: Sometimes I run into this issue after new updates to R or Rstudio. My recommendation is to restart your R session and try using the RStudio package installation context to load all the dependencies one by one. When that fails me, I re-install R.

Comment: try installing the package that the message says is missing with `install.packages("zip")`

Comment: @MrFlick That worked. I feel quite silly. Thank you!!